# What is meant by bhaya(fear) yogi?

Tags: terminology, yogi

What is meant by bhaya yogi? And is the term bhaya yogi anywhere mentioned in scriptures?

Comment: I'm hearing this term for the first time .. may be Rakesh Joshi knows about it.

Comment: Bhaya (भय) refers to “fear” and represents a type of Ādhyātmika pain of the mental (mānasa) type, according to the Viṣṇu-purāṇa 6.5.1-6.( https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/bhaya). So bhaya yogi may refer to one , who transcended/got rid of the fear @hanugm

Comment: Where have you heard/read this term from?

Comment: @Paṇḍyā pravachanas.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Regarding Marica.......